# How can I create extension methods with static return type?

Tags: c#, static, extension-methods

I was trying to write a simple extension method for `Color` static class which return Black and White equivalent of that color.
The problem is that extention methods can't return **Static** types...
So, how can I do this?! please help me.

Comment: So you want a method `Color ToBlackOrWhite(this Color color)` where `Color` is a static class? That won't work. Not only can't you have a static class as return type, but also not as parameter type. Because it doesn't make any sense: How would you pass a color to the method if you can't create instances of `Color`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that NO method can return a static type. Static classes are stateless (or have only static state), and thus have only one "instance" that is globally accessible from any code referencing the namespace.

You can return a Color; the Color class itself, though it has static members, is not static, and so many instances of Colors can exist. You can also apply an extension method to a Color. If you do this, then you can call an extension method on one of the static members of the non-static Color struct:

```
public static class MyColorsExtensions
{

   public static Color ToGreyScale(this Color theColor) { ... }

}

...

var greyFromBlue = Color.Blue.ToGreyScale();
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're referring to [`System.Drawing.Color`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14w97wkc.aspx) - it's not a static class ... it's a struct. You should be able to return an instance of it from a method. It just so happens that the `Color` structure includes static members to represent `specific colors` - like:  `Color.Black` and `Color.White`.

If you're not referring to that type, then please post a short sample of the code that fails.

Comment: just to be clear, Color can also be used with arbitrary ARGB values.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to understand what you are trying to say, but if you are trying to create a extension method for a static class, that is impossible because extension methods are for class instances.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? This is an extension method returning a static color struct.

```
public static class ColorExtensions
{
    private static Color MYCOLOR = Color.Black;
    public static Color BlackAndWhiteEquivalent(this Color obj)
    {
        // stubbed in - replace with logic for find actual
        // equivalent color given what obj is
        return MYCOLOR;
    }
}
```

and the test

```
    [Test]
    public void FindBlackAndWhiteColorEquivalent()
    {
        Color equivalentColor = Color.Black.BlackAndWhiteEquivalent();
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
public static class Colores
{
public static Color Rojo = Color.FromArgb(0xE51600);
public static Color Azul = Color.FromArgb(0x004183);
public static Color Verde = Color.FromArgb(0x00865A);
public static Color Plata = Color.FromArgb(0xC4C5C7);
public static Color Gris = Color.FromArgb(0x58585A);
public static Color Cafe = Color.FromArgb(0x632600);
public static Color Negro = Color.Black;
}
```